# XML Serialization to child nodes without a new object

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I am using xml serialization, with rectangles but this is producing some nasty XML...

My class is something like this:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class myObject
    {
       public Rectangle Region { get; set; }

       //Some other properties and methods...
    }
```

and that give me this when i serialize it to XML:

```
    <myObject>
      <Region>
        <Location>
          <X>141</X>
          <Y>93</Y>
        </Location>
        <Size>
          <Width>137</Width>
          <Height>15</Height>
        </Size>
        <X>141</X>
        <Y>93</Y>
        <Width>137</Width>
        <Height>15</Height>
      </Region>
      ...
    </myObject>
```

Yuck!

I am hoping that I can either suppress the `Size` and `Location` properties on the `Rectangle`, or perhaps use backing variables and `[XmlIgnore]` to  end up with something like this:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class myObject
    {
       [XmlElement("????")]
       public int RegionX;

       [XmlElement("????")]
       public int RegionY;

       [XmlElement("????")]
       public int RegionHeight;

       [XmlElement("????")]
       public int RegionWidth;

       [XmlIgnore]
       public Rectangle Region {get { return new Rectangle(RegionX, RegionY, RegionWidth, RegionHeight);}

       //Some other properties and methods...
    }
```

hopefully giving me something like:

```
    <myObject>
      <Region>
        <X>141</X>
        <Y>93</Y>
        <Width>137</Width>
        <Height>15</Height>
      </Region>
      ...
    </myObject>
```

Not so good in the code, but the XML will be edited by people so it would be good to get something which works there...

Any ides what might go in the "????"? or another way of doing this?

I would prefer not to have to implement my own version of `Rectangle`...

Comment: If you separate your data serialization layer from your business objects, you can do whatever you like. Create your own `RectangleDTO` object which has properties such as `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`, then run your DTO objects through a converter to change them to/from your business objects.

Comment: I have to echo what Chris says; if your domain objects aren't the shape you want for serialization, then don't fight the serializer - add a DTO layer instead.

Comment: Why would people edit the XML manually? Editors are there for that. Anyway, you could simply create property that expose your `Rectangle` fields and serialize them instead of the field itself. If you implement the ISerializable interface, you can pretty much do anything. However, I'm not sure if the XMLSerializer use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comments guys, i ended going down a sort of DTO route - I implemented my own Struct - `XmlRectangle`, holding the four int values i need  decorated with `[Serializable]`. I added implicit conversion operators so i could use it as a `Rectangle`:

```
[Serializable]
public struct XmlRectangle
{
    #endregion Public Properties

    public int X {get; set; }
    public int Y {get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }

    #endregion Public Properties

    #region Implicit Conversion Operators

    public static implicit operator Rectangle(XmlRectangle xmlRectangle)
    {
        return new Rectangle(xmlRectangle.X, xmlRectangle.Y, xmlRectangle.Width, xmlRectangle.Height);
    }

    public static implicit operator XmlRectangle(Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        return result = new XmlRectangle(){ X = rectangle.X, Y = Rectangle.Y, Height = Rectangle.Height, width  = Rectangle.Width };
    }

    #endregion Implicit Conversion Operators
}
```

Then the class which held it as data had a `Rectangle` property exposing it as an `XmlRectangle` to the serializer the like this:

```
[XmlElement("Region",typeof(XmlRectangle))]
public Rectangle Region { get; set; }
```